# How can I create a google app scrip that allows users see only a specified range using email address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a google spreadsheet with 36 similar tables on the same sheet. Each user can only see range of cells assigned to them based on their email address. The range of cells displayed will be preset based on the email of the user. Please, how can I do this using Google Apps Script.

Comment: NamedRanges seems like an easy choice.

Comment: Do you have any code you're working on? Also, a copy of the spreadsheet (free of sensitive information) could be useful for others to help you.